# Using a variable to hold a Bash array name

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

website_array_$w are w number arrays created by a given argument in command line. I am trying to create a new array temp and store the specific website_array_$w inside it each time. This doesn't seem to work and I get:

```
temp=${website_array_$w[*]}: bad substitution
```

What am I doing wrong? After that I want to create a new array random_temp that contains $f random values of array temp.

```
for ((w=0; w<"$3"; w++)) do
    eval echo 'temp=${website_array_$w[*]}'
    for ((p=0; p<"$4"; p++)) do
         for((i=0; i<"$f"; i++)) do
            eval "random_temp=${temp[$RANDOM % ${#temp[@]}]}"
         done
    done
done
```

Comment: Instead of putting variables into the variable name, use an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nameref (works with Bash versions 4.3 and above):

```
declare -n temp=website_array_$w || { echo "ERROR: Need bash 4.3 or newer" >&2; exit 1; }
```

And then use it:

```
random_temp=${temp[$RANDOM % ${#temp[@]}]}
```

---

See:

- [BashFAQ/006 - How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)
- [How to use a variable as part of an array name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412812/201820) on Unix & Linux StackExchange